# Where were the dragons kept before the first task?

Tags: harry-potter

The Hogsmeade trip was on the Saturday before the first task.

> On the Saturday before the first task, all students in the third year
>   and above were permitted to visit the village of Hogsmeade.

and Harry visited Hagrid same night to see the dragons brought in by Charlie and others. As we know the first task was on Tuesday.

> ‘Let’s just try and keep you alive until Tuesday evening,’ she said
>   desperately, ‘and then we can worry about Karkaroff.’

So where did they keep the dragons for 2 days without anyone noticing?

Comment: In the Forbidden Forest IIRC. That's where Hagrid took Harry to give him a peek.

Comment: Wasn't there Centaurs and other things in forbidden forest?

Comment: Yes... but where is the the problem? Did you read the book?

Comment: yup i did. so keeping dragons doesn't endanger other creatures of the forests.

Comment: @DheerajKumar There were other creatures in there. The Dragons were however penned up and under supervision of trained staff from the ministry, including Ron's elder brother, (Charlie, I think). There was never any danger for other inhabitants of the forest

Answer (score 5):

## In their dragon enclosure.

Charlie and his team brought a sort of cage-like structure with them to contain the dragons when they came up to Hogwarts.

> Four fully grown, enormous, vicious-looking dragons were rearing on their hind legs inside **an enclosure fenced with thick planks of wood**, roaring and snorting - torrents of fire were shooting into the dark sky from their open, fanged mouths, fifty feet above the ground on their outstretched necks.
>   <sub>*(Goblet of Fire, Chapter 19, The Hungarian Horntail).*</sub>

The dragons were also chained down. They weren't free to roam wherever they wanted.

> At least thirty wizards, seven or eight to each dragon, were attempting to control them, pulling on **the chains connected to heavy leather straps around their necks and legs.**
>   <sub>*(Goblet of Fire, Chapter 19, The Hungarian Horntail).*</sub>

As to where the enclosure was positioned, it was in the Forbidden Forest, quite close to the perimeter.

> She was leading him towards the place where the dragons were, **around the edge of the Forest**, but when they approached the clump of trees behind which the enclosure would be clearly visible, Harry saw that a tent had been erected, its entrance facing them, screening the dragons from view.
>   <sub>*(Goblet of Fire, Chapter 20, The First Task)*.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the dragons were kept in the enclosure where Harry saw Charlie and the other wizards trying to keep the dragons down.